# Are there good practices if any avoiding out of bounds index error when looping TStringList items?

Tags: delphi, pascal, tstringlist

:)

First thing, my code

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var tempId,i:integer;
begin
tempId:=strtoint(edit5.Text);
plik:=TStringList.Create;
plik.LoadFromFile('.\klienci\'+linia_klient[id+1]+'.txt');
if (plik.Count=1) then
  begin
  label6.Caption:='then';
    if (tempId=StrToInt(plik[0])) then
      begin
      Label6.Caption:='Zwrócono';
      plik.Delete(0);
    end
  end
else
for i:=0 to plik.Count-2 do
  begin
    if (tempId=StrToInt(plik[i])) then
    begin
      Label6.Caption:='Zwrócono';
      plik.Delete(i);
    end;
  end;
plik.SaveToFile('.\klienci\'+linia_klient[id+1]+'.txt');
plik.Free;
end;
```

- When `for i:=0 to plik.Count-2 do` I can delete any element but not
  last.
- When `for i:=0 to plik.Count-1 do` I can delete any element without
  but from end to start. Because otherwise *List index out of bounds*.

What's going one? How can I safety search and remove elements from TStringList?

Comment: This is a duplicate in the fact, there are tons of such questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When deleting intems from list you want to use `downto` loop, ie

```
for i := plik.Count-1 downto 0 do
  begin
    if (tempId=StrToInt(plik[i])) then
    begin
      Label6.Caption:='Zwrócono';
      plik.Delete(i);
    end;
  end;
```

This ensures that if you delete item, the loop index stays valid as you move from the end of the list dowards beginning of the list.

Answer (score 5):

This is a classic problem. A `for` loop evaluates the loop bounds once at the beginning of the loop, so you run off the end which explains your index out of bounds errors.

But even if `for` loops evaluated loop bounds every time like a `while` does that would not really help. When you delete an element, you reduce the `Count` by 1 and move the remaining elements down one in the list. So you change the index of all those still to be processed elements.

The standard trick is to loop down the list:

```
for i := List.Count-1 downto 0 do
  if DeleteThisItem(i) then
    List.Delete(i);
```

When you write it this way, the call to `Delete` affects the indices of elements that have *already* been processed.

Comment: but ain was the first, but thanks for fulfillment his answser :)

Comment: @Dudi You should accept the best answer, by your judgement, as opposed to the first. I'm not saying that you haven't done that, and only you can decide. But remember that it takes more time to produce a better answer. If someone came along with a painstakingly produced, comprehensive answer that was much better than the answers you have now, you should accept that one. For example, P.A.'s answer is rather more comprehensive than the others.

Answer (score 2):

```
For I := stringlist.count-1 downto 0 do
```

Now you can delete all items without any error

Comment: Damn I was looking for that solution :)... wait for it.
I didn't even know that you can decrement var in delphi.

Comment: Don't be hurry, you will be learn alo of things about Delphi . Just keep in study

Answer (score 2):

in an ascending loop like `for i:=1 to count` you just can't delete items of the list you are iterating over.

there are several solutions depending on the overall logic of what you want to achieve.

1. you may change the `for` loop into a `while` loop that reevaluates `count` and don't increment index on the delete iteration
2. you may reverse the loop, kinda `for i:=count downto 1`
3. instead of `delete`, you may create a temporary list and copy there only the items you want to keep, and recopy it back.

Comment: Why did you revert my edit where I corrected the indexing errors in your answer?

Comment: my examples on how to build the loop are correct, I don't show how to use the index `items[i-1]`. In fact, I always prefer the pascalish counting from 1 instead of the stupid 0 based count.

Comment: Indexing is zero based, no discussion. Counting is not.

Comment: Surely this makes for awkward code. Sometimes you index i-1 and sometimes not. For example when you do IndexOf and store the result, do you add 1 to it?  Sounds like a recipe for pain to me.

Comment: Good practice should be promoted!

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, using a `downto` loop is usually the best choice.  Of course, it does change the semantics of the loop so it runs backwards instead of forwards.  If you want to continue looping forwards, you have to use a `while` loop instead, eg:

```
I := 0;
while I < plik.Count do 
begin 
  if (tempId = StrToInt(plik[I])) then 
  begin 
    ...
    plik.Delete(I); 
  end else
    Inc(I); 
end;
```

Or:

```
var
  CurIdx, Cnt: Integer;

CurIdx := 0;
Cnt := plik.Count;
for I := 0 to Cnt-1 do 
begin 
  if (tempId = StrToInt(plik[CurIdx])) then 
  begin 
    ...
    plik.Delete(CurIdx); 
  end else
    Inc(CurIdx); 
end;
```